# How to permanently unpublish a free Android app?

Tags: android, google-play

I recently unpublished a free app, changed the package name, and uploaded the same app (under a different developer's account) as a paid app.

The problem is that as soon as the [paid app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=worldofluciddreaming.apps.paid.tenstepstoluciddreams) was published, the [free app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=worldofluciddreaming.apps.tenstepstoluciddreams) has become available again!

I've doubled-checked on my developer's account, and the free app is still "unpublished".

Does anyone know why the free app became available again and how I can permanently make it unavailable?

Comment: tell google about this :)

Comment: I'm guessing, but I would think that the the criteria they use include private keys, apk names and apk sizes or some combination of all three.

Comment: Aha.  I signed both apps with the same key.  So changing the keys might work?  Let me try that.

Comment: The free app will remain visible to accounts that have previously installed it, even after you've unpublished it. Try logging out of all accounts and checking, or using a new one.

Comment: Please be aware that Google expressly prohibits what you're attempting to do, so circumventing their policies by creating a second developer account might actually be a violation of their TOS.

Comment: @323go, wow really?  I made an app for a client who originally wanted the app to be free.  After a few months they changed their mind and wanted it to be paid.  So I let them create a developer's account so they are in control of any income, unpublished the free app and let them publish the app as paid.  Is this prohibited by Google?!

Comment: @RaghavSood that's exactly right!  It was only showing up for us because we were logged into our Google accounts and had previously downloaded the free app.  Thanks!  If you chuck your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, from http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/console.html: "If you publish your app as free, it must remain free. Free apps can be downloaded by any users in Google Play."

Comment: It could be argued that if you change the package name and release key, it's no longer the same app, so the prohibitions for making a free app paid would no longer be relevant. The idea is to prevent skewed download counts and feedback; this wouldn't apply if the app is no longer identified with the free app. You might want to look through the TOS, just to be sure.

Comment: I see.  If the purpose is to prevent skewed download counts and feedback we should be alirght.  By making the app paid we've lost all the positive feedback and download count from the free app (ie, it is not carried over to the paid app).  Cheers for the heads up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Play keeps your app visible to those who purchased it or installed it, even after you unpublish it. They say it prevents users from getting disoriented if one of their apps suddenly disappears from the Play Store.

Try logging out of all accounts, or signing in with a new account and looking for the free app again. If unpublished it shouldn't show up.

Also note that similar to publishing, apps may take a while to disappear after being unpublished.